# HTML5 native application with node-webkit

Tags: wpf, node.js, node-webkit

We have a C++ windows desktop application that does factory production inspection using vision.
The application acquires images from i.e. GigE cameras, using native drivers and software libraries,  and runs third party native C++ algorithms to perform inspections. We inspect up to 1000 parts per minute with several cameras.
Actually we have an old styled MFC GUI, that show images (even ‘live’ images) and the results of the several inspections threads.
 
We are building a new WPF rich GUI, but we have doubt about the future of WPF and the use of a mixed .net application (and not to mention when you have crashes in the xaml stack you end up with an indecipherable call stack).
 
We had  the idea to build a HTML5 native application with node-webkit.  We don’t need a multi OS application, but we see the opportunity to share some portion of the GUI to be used with different devices. 
First of all: is this a good idea and is this technology suited for these kind of applications? 
If so, we see two options:

1. adding our inspections threads directly in nw.exe (recompiling it), and write native nodejs extensions to get data for the html gui.
2. use nw.exe and write native nodejs extensions both for
   inspections threads  and to get data for the html gui.

Which one would be better?

Comment: Did you think about making http api in your current application, so you can comunicate over http to get images? You can start and stop that server when you start and stop a GUI

Comment: This was our first attempt, with a nodejs server with a native module that exposed some API to get the images from the GUI. 
It was not that fast (you cannot go to 30 fps) and was CPU consuming (copy image to the shared memory from our MFC application, get it in the node process and copy to a node::Buffer and send it over http...; but it was fine for a 'slow to update' client connected from another PC). 
Now we would like our core application run ‘in-process’ with the html5 GUI.